# How to “follow” relationships in orm query?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to find the grandchildren given an attribute of the grandfather

Given these models:

```
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

class B(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "b"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    a_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("a.id")

class C(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "c"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    b_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("b.id")
```

I need to query all `C` by any of its related `A` fields.

Like in [django lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

`C.objects.filter(b__a__name='a')`

Answer (score 0):

You can query `C` by any related `A` field by joining the `B` and `A` model to the query, this example retrieves all `C` objects with a `A` whose name is `'a'`:

`C.query.join(B, A).filter(A.name == 'a')`

This can be as deep as you’d like.